# How to update the main angular component on routing?

Tags: angular, routes, session-storage

I want my entire app to have the same nav bar, so naturally I put it in app.component.html. This nav bar contains the email of the logged user, and so should appear on the nav bar after connection. In order to keep that info even after a page refresh, I keep the email in session storage.

The thing is that, in order for the HTML code to pick up the value added in session storage after logging in, app.component has to refresh. But it's not happening when going to the next page after logging in. I have to refresh the page for the info to appear on the navbar, and I clearly don't want to do that.

I could create a nav bar component, but I don't want to have to include it everywhere on the app, even though it would somewhat solve my problem.

Some code next, just to visualize things a bit better

[image: App.component.ts]

[image: App.component.html]

[image: Auth.service authentication function]

Comment: I'd rather make the userEmail var in the authService and after login set the email for it and then place it inside the navbar like ```{{authService.userEmail}}```. This way it will be keeped and if you change it it will refresh it automatically as well.

Comment: I thought of that as well, but the main feature of session storage is that the value doesn't disapear upon refreshing the page, whereas for any variable in a service, its value is lost when refreshing

Comment: Yeah, the storage will keep the data, but the ngOnInit will run only once. As I said, place it inside the service and it won't disappear. I recommend @HoseinGhanbari's answer, I use that as well!

Comment: I already tried, and it disappears when refreshing the page. It's only when calling the sign in function that the value is set, not when refreshing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you using a simple **EventEmitter** or **RxJS Subject/BehaviorSubject**.

`user = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);`
this user will be a property of you auth service.

each time a user successfully signed-up or logged-in, you will notify all the 
subscribers with the new value.
`this.user.next(user);`

and for the auto-login, auto-logout functionality you may use localStorage
`localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(user));`

wherever you need the current user, for example on navbar, subscribe to it and it will gives you the latest changes.

```
this.userSub = this.authService.user.subscribe(user => {

});
```

and finally make sure unsubscribe from user subscription wherever you subscribed

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.userSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

for auto-login functionality, even if the page refreshed, we stored current user object in local-storage whenever user logged-in/signed-up successfully, so by using `ngOnInit` hook on the app.component (a parental component) we can achieve what you need by retrieving and restoring the user object to angular-app.

```
autoLogin() {
  const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
  if (!userData) {
    return;
  }

  const loadedUser = new User(
    userData.email,
    userData.token,
    new Date(userData.expiresIn)
  );

  if (loadedUser.token) {
    this.user.next(loadedUser);
  }
}
```

you may check token validity and expiresIn before emitting the restored user.
make sure to call autoLogin() as the angular-app starts.

Comment: Your solution works in a way: it allows me to display the email in the navbar right after logging in, so that's good, thank you! But it did not help with the fact that it disappears uponj refreshing the page, I had to add "this.userMail = sessionStorage.getItem("userEmail");" in app.component ngOnInit(), as the BehaviorSubject has it's value set only when logging in.

Comment: I updated the answer, with the autoLogin() added. you dont need sessionStorage any  more. as we use localStorage. Hope this helps you.