# How To Trigger Person Click Remember Me Or Not

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to make remember me on page login. When click remember me and if user close browser without logout, their can open again without need to login. My problem is, how I need to trigger to make a different between user who **click** remember me and user who **not click** remember me?.

**HTML**

```
<form  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" #form="ngForm">
  <ng-content select='h3'></ng-content>
    <label> 
    Email Address
    <input type="email" name="email">
  </label>

    <label> 
    Password
    <input type="password" name="password">
  </label>
     <label style="display: flex">
    <input type="checkbox"> 
    Rememeber me.
  </label>
<button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

**Component**

```
    ngOnInit() {
     this.AutoLogin();
    }

    onSubmit() {
    this.auth.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe((res) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', res['accessToken']);
      localStorage.setItem('name', res['name']);
      localStorage.setItem('role', res['role']);
      localStorage.setItem('email', res['email']);
      localStorage.setItem('userId', res['userId']);
      this.toastrService.success('Successfully Login!');
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    },
    (err) => {

    });
  }

    AutoLogin(){
        var accessTokenObj = localStorage.getItem("token");
    console.log(accessTokenObj);
        if (accessTokenObj) {
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        } else {
          console.log("You need to login")
        }
       }
```

Comment: I'd save in the local storage the state of `rememberMe` when someone logs-in, then use that value in the `AutoLogin` function. This way you don't know who has checked the `rememberMe` box. If you need this information you could also send its state while loggin' in and save it into the DB.

Comment: You need JWT and stores it on client and check validity on server for login process

Comment: I've edit my question.

Comment: This is something you can implement on the server-side instead of client-side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you bind the remember me value to a model and save to local storage, do a check in the autoLogin()

**HTML**

```
<form  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" #form="ngForm">
  <ng-content select='h3'></ng-content>
    <label> 
    Email Address
    <input type="email" name="email">
  </label>

    <label> 
    Password
    <input type="password" name="password">
  </label>
     <label style="display: flex">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="rememberMe"> 
    Remember me.
   </label>
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
 </form>
```

**Component**

```
rememberMe: boolean;
ngOnInit() {
     this.rememberMe = false;
     this.AutoLogin();
    }

    onSubmit() {
    this.auth.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe((res) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', res['accessToken']);
      localStorage.setItem('name', res['name']);
      localStorage.setItem('role', res['role']);
      localStorage.setItem('email', res['email']);
      localStorage.setItem('userId', res['userId']);
      // Save value to local storage
      if(rememberMe) {
        localStorage.setItem('rememberMe', 'yes')
      }
      this.toastrService.success('Successfully Login!');
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    },
    (err) => {

    });
  }

    AutoLogin(){
        const accessTokenObj = localStorage.getItem("token");
        // Retrieve rememberMe value from local storage
        const rememberMe = localStorage.getItem('rememberMe');
    console.log(accessTokenObj);
        if (accessTokenObj && rememberMe == 'yes') {
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        } else {
          console.log("You need to login")
        }
       }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much brother... This what I want

Answer (score 0):

if by the terms "remember me" you mean auto-login on the client side, please take a look at the auto-login functionality described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60323336/6543507

but "remember me" functionality somehow related to your backend and authentication service when you need to remembering users while authenticating them, which lead to store special data on the server and retrieve it when required. for this purpose take a look at laravel site on https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#remembering-users

Comment: For now my auto login working for all user who click remember me or not...My problem is, I want just allow user who click remember me can auto redirect to home without login when user not logout or clear history

Comment: you have to check the localStorage which stored the remember_me on the ngOnInit hook of the whole app component, like AppComponent.From there if the user authentication data available on the localStorage, then you auto-login the user and do the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be more easy:

```
if(rememberMe){
  localStorage.setItem("token", MY_TOKEN);
}else{
  sessionStorage.setItem("token", MY_TOKEN);
}
```

Now create an [RouteGuard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) for authentication.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(public router: Router) {}
  canActivate(): boolean {
    var token = localStorage.getItem("token") || sessionStorage.getItem("token");
    if (!myNotAuthenticatedMethod(token)) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```